# Material UI dialog, fit image inside dialog's height

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui

I have a Material UI dialog that will display a bunch of images, the images have landscapes or portraits aspect ratio. And they might have different resolutions as well. I want to find an elegant solution to maintain the dialog's height 80% of the screen.

But fit the whole image inside the dialog, without needing to scroll, here's a [SandboxExample](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-eet8l?file=/demo.js).

Or find the snippet bellow:

```
<div>
  <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
    Open dialog
  </Button>
  <Dialog
    open={open}
    onClose={handleClose}
    hasCloseButton
    style={{ maxWidth: "100%", maxHeight: "100%" }}
  >
    <img
      style={{ maxWidth: "100%", height: 'auto' }}
      src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1565992441121-4367c2967103"
      alt="image"
    />
  </Dialog>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not possible with your pre-requisites. if you want to have a fixed height without scroll for images with different aspect-ratios the best you can have is a centered image that will eventually have some parts cut off

Comment: the dialog height can change, it's not mandatory to have fixed height, the main thing is to not go out of the screen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to achieve that you may use viewheight unit (vh). Combine `maxHeight`(based on vh) along `maxWidth: 100%`. Dialog uses 32px as margin, hence you could use `maxHeight: "calc(100vh - 64px)"` or you can use a custom vh like `maxHeight: "80vh"`

```
   <img
      style={{ maxWidth: "100%", maxHeight: "calc(100vh - 64px)" }}
      src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1565992441121-4367c2967103"
      alt="image"
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you set the image height to 100% the element that contains it?

On your sandbox I did this: `style={{ width: 'auto', height: '100%' }}` and it seemed to work.

Here is the complete code:

```
<div>
  <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
    Open dialog
  </Button>
  <Dialog
    open={open}
    onClose={handleClose}
    hasCloseButton
    style={{ maxWidth: "100%", maxHeight: "100%" }}
  >
    <img
      style={{ width: 'auto', height: '100%' }}
      src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1565992441121-4367c2967103"
      alt="image"
    />
  </Dialog>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think it works... I just tried it and nothing changes @Felipe

Comment: Doesn't work as well. However, the solution shared in the accepted answer worked perfectly fine.